# Monitoring Code/Method-level Statistics using AppDynamics

Tags: performance-testing, jprofiler, glassfish-4.1, dottrace, appdynamics

I am now working on Performance Testing of a Java Application that runs on GlassFish Server 4.1.

After going through some statistics that I got from AppDynamics tool, I find that there is no possibility for me to drill down to code/method level issues. For example, I can see the time taken by each method or function using dotTrace or JProfiler but AppDynamics tool seems to skip all these features.

I was also looking for a free solution, hence I choose AppDynamics. Now I feel I am not on the right track. Can someone let me know more about this tool if I am missing something or suggest any other quick and easy solution to this.

Is there a possibility that the monitors on GlassFish server 4.1 can do the same for no cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, monitoring tools cannot record method-level data continuously, because they have to operate at a much lower level of overhead compared to profiling tools. They focus on "business transactions" that show you high-level performance measurements with associated semantic information, such as the processing of an order in your web shop.

Method level data only comes in when these business transactions are too slow. The monitoring tool will then start sampling the executing thread and show you a call tree or hot spots. However, you will not get this information for the entire VM for a continuous interval like you're used to from a profiler.

You mentioned JProfiler, so if you are already familiar with that tool, you might be interested in [perfino](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/perfino/overview.html) as a monitoring solution. It shows you samples on the method level and has cross-over functionality into profiling with the native JVMTI interface. It allows you to do [full sampling of the entire JVM](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/perfino/help/doc/main/profiling.html) for a selected amount of time and look at the results in the JProfiler GUI.

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler and perfino.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ingo. I can see from the perfino screenshots that it has some extra features as to what AppDyanmics can do. But at this moment I have no choice to move to another solution. At this point, I would also like to know the new monitoring capabilities of GlassFish 4.1 whether it will be of any help to me.